# Choosing a boundary for integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have the following differential equation 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\mu e^{cx}f(x)\right) = -\mu\left(\frac{a xe^{-cx}}{a x+x-1}\right)
$$
that I am trying to integrate to find $f(x)$ with the boundary constraint that $f(1) =1$. The integrating factor $\mu$ is given by 
$$
\mu = e^{\frac{a c}{1+a}x}\left((a+1)x-1\right)^{\frac{1+a+ac}{(1+a)^2}}
$$
If we integrate this with a lower limit of $x$ then 
$$
\mu e^{ct}f(t)\big|_x = -\int_x  \mu\left(\frac{a te^{-ct}}{a t+t-1}\right)dt
$$
However, what would be a sensible upper limit so that I can find $f(x) = ?$. The integrating factor has a zero at $x=1/(a+1)$. Would it make sense to integrate up to this boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused. Why don't you just integrate between $1$ and $x$ so you get to use your initial condition $f(1)=1$?
You will get
$$\mu(x) e^{ct}f(t)\big|_1^x = -\int_1^x  \mu(t)\left(\frac{a te^{-ct}}{a t+t-1}\right)dt$$ which gives 
$$\mu(x) e^{cx}f(x)-\mu(1) e^{c}1 = -\int_1^x  \mu(t)\left(\frac{a te^{-ct}}{a t+t-1}\right)dt$$ and so you get
$$f(x) =\frac{\mu(1) e^{c}}{\mu(x) e^{cx}} -\frac{1}{\mu(x) e^{cx}}\int_1^x  \mu(t)\left(\frac{a te^{-ct}}{a t+t-1}\right)dt,$$which holds for all $x \ne 1/(a+1)$. 
I doubt the integral can be solved, since it looks a lot like a Gamma function.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I was wondering if you could take a quick look at the following question, which attempts to solve a similar integral to this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889856/integral-of-special-function